# Closing Excel processes in Windows after user opens Excel files for data input

Tags: excel, marshalling, vb.net-2010

Program opens Excels, reads sheets and fills arrays for data from each sheet.  For each Excel opened to get input data, there will be an Excel process in the Windows process list.  If the user opens many Excels over time during run-time, there will be many Excel processes running in Windows.

Problem is, if you go to a folder and try to open one of the Excel's that was opened programatically, it will be read only since the Excel process running in Windows is holding on to it.  Each Excel process in Windows needs to be terminated in order to release each Excal that was opened programatically.

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

   ' Create new Application.
        Dim rXL As New Excel.Application
        Dim rWB As Excel.Workbook
        '   Dim rSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim rRng As Excel.Range
        Dim buffmatrix(,) As Object
        rWB = rXL.Workbooks.Open(filename)
        Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet
        For i = 1 To rWB.Sheets.Count To 1 Step -1
            ' Get sheet.
            sheet = rWB.Sheets(i)
            ' Get range.
            Dim r As Excel.Range = sheet.UsedRange
            If r.Rows.Count = 0 Then Exit For
            ' Load all cells into 2d array.
            Dim eCellArray As System.Array = r.Value
            ' eCellArray is used for processing here 
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Sheet)
            rRng = Nothing
        Next

        rWB = Nothing
        rXL = Nothing
```

The Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Sheet) command in the loop above is not working, that is, it is not terminating the Excel process in Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using this code

```
    WorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook WorkBook
    ExcelInstance As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass

    WorkBook.Close(_missing, _missing, _missing)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(WorkBook)
    ExcelInstance.Quit()
    ExcelInstance.Application.Quit()  
      System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ExcelInstance)
       GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: Worked like a charm - so thanks.   It was very annoying having so many Excel processes open.